# Distance to the object using stereo camera

Tags: opencv, camera, distance, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

Is there a way to calculate the distance to specific object using stereo camera? 
Is there an equation or something to get distance using disparity or angle?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I reworded your second sentence a bit.

Comment: Try to mark answers accepted if they do answer your problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**NOTE:** Everything described here can be found in the Learning OpenCV book in the chapters on camera calibration and stereo vision. You should read these chapters to get a better understanding of the steps below.

One approach that do not require you to measure all the camera intrinsics and extrinsics yourself is to use openCVs calibration functions. Camera intrinsics (lens distortion/skew etc) can be calculated with cv::calibrateCamera, while the extrinsics (relation between left and right camera) can be calculated with cv::stereoCalibrate. These functions take a number of points in pixel coordinates and tries to map them to real world object coordinates. CV has a neat way to get such points, print out a black-and-white chessboard and use the cv::findChessboardCorners/cv::cornerSubPix functions to extract them. Around 10-15 image pairs of chessboards should do.

The matrices calculated by the calibration functions can be saved to disc so you don't have to repeat this process every time you start your application. You get some neat matrices here that allow you to create a rectification map (cv::stereoRectify/cv::initUndistortRectifyMap) that can later be applied to your images using cv::remap. You also get a neat matrix called Q, which is a disparity-to-depth matrix.

The reason to rectify your images is that once the process is complete for a pair of images (assuming your calibration is correct), every pixel/object in one image can be found on the **same row** in the other image.

There are a few ways you can go from here, depending on what kind of features you are looking for in the image. One way is to use CVs stereo correspondence functions, such as Stereo Block Matching or Semi Global Block Matching. This will give you a disparity map for the entire image which can be transformed to 3D points using the Q matrix (cv::reprojectImageTo3D).

The downfall of this is that unless there is much texture information in the image, CV isn't really very good at building a dense disparity map (you will get gaps in it where it couldn't find the correct disparity for a given pixel), so another approach is to find the points you want to match yourself. Say you find the feature/object in x=40,y=110 in the left image and x=22 in the right image (since the images are rectified, they should have the same y-value). The disparity is calculated as d = 40 - 22 = 18.

Construct a cv::Point3f(x,y,d), in our case (40,110,18). Find other interesting points the same way, then send all of the points to cv::perspectiveTransform (with the Q matrix as the transformation matrix, essentially this function is cv::reprojectImageTo3D but for sparse disparity maps) and the output will be points in an XYZ-coordinate system with the left camera at the center.

Comment: great summary of the process, not many people actually do the summary but just quote "go look at chap12!". Thanks for taking the time to explain :)

Comment: @Orka
great summary and really thank you,
but can you please help me how to get the disparity for each point using openCv ?

Answer (score 6):

I am still working on it, so I will not post entire source code yet. But I will give you a conceptual solution.

You will need the following data as input (for both cameras):

- camera position
- camera point of interest (point at which camera is looking)
- camera resolution (horizontal and vertical)
- camera field of view angles (horizontal and vertical)

You can measure the last one yourself, by placing the camera on a piece of paper and drawing two lines and measuring an angle between these lines.

Cameras do not have to be aligned in any way, you only need to be able to see your object in both cameras.

Now calculate a vector from each camera to your object. You have (X,Y) pixel coordinates of the object from each camera, and you need to calculate a vector (X,Y,Z). Note that in the simple case, where the object is seen right in the middle of the camera, the solution would simply be (camera.PointOfInterest - camera.Position).

Once you have both vectors pointing at your target, lines defined by these vectors should cross in one point in ideal world. In real world they would not because of small measurement errors and limited resolution of cameras. So use the link below to calculate the distance vector between two lines.

[Distance between two lines](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0106/algorithm_0106.htm)

In that link: P0 is your first cam position, Q0 is your second cam position and u and v are vectors starting at camera position and pointing at your target.

You are not interested in the actual distance, they want to calculate. You need the vector Wc - we can assume that the object is in the middle of Wc. Once you have the position of your object in 3D space you also get whatever distance you like.

I will post the entire source code soon.

Comment: you ever make the 'full' source code available? I'd be interested in seeing (yet another) example of obtaining depth from two images

Comment: @Eiver. Could please give some link of examples as you implemented? Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Eiver. can you please share your code with us ? thanks in advance

Comment: @MohamedAM-Hassan Hi! Sorry, but I was completely redirected to other things and was never able to finish this.

Answer (score 2):

I have the source code for detecting human face and returns not only depth but also real world coordinates with left camera (or right camera, I couldn't remember) being origin. It is adapted from source code from "Learning OpenCV" and refer to some websites to get it working. The result is generally quite accurate.

Comment: Hi Tony, can you give me some more details about this source code?

Comment: He sayd, get a book "Learning OpenCV", this is really worth of investment. Also you can find source code for book in Google but again, without book you get no good explanation what is going inside of it.